# Django AbstractUser doesn't show model

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm a django beginner and i want to add a booleanfield to AbstractUser, but it's not showing the booleanfield in the admin.

models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    selected = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['selected',]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

admin.py

```
class MyUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    form = MyUserChangeForm
    list_display = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'is_staff', 'selected')

admin.site.register(CustomUser, UserAdmin)
```

settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'football_app.CustomUser'
```

Comment: can you add `UserAdmin` class?

Comment: if i list display it, it will show, but i want it for each user, so i can select or deselect it

Comment: Are you done makemigrations and migrate?

Comment: yes, i've done them

Comment: Post you UserChangeForm

Comment: it is posted, look better

Comment: if you've done then in your database it must create `customuser` table.

Comment: it does create customuser, it's not showing the booleanfield in the admin for users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in admin.py file change 
`class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):` to `class UserAdmin(CustomUser):`

**EDIT**: update your class like this

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'is_staff', 'selected')

    class Meta:
       model = CustomUser
```

Comment: it shows it now, but list_display doesn't show anymore the fields and the whole admin for user changed

Comment: isn't it possible to keep the user admin as it is and just add the field to the finish and list display it?

Comment: If you want use  `selected` field every where you must select correct model class,

Comment: `form = MyUserChangeForm`
comment this line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142808/discussion-between-nita-alexandru-and-mubariz-feyziyev).

Answer (score 0):

You need to unregister current User admin first.

```
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(CustomUser, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: that's not it :\

Comment: What's not it? It is literally from the docs and it's not in your code. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Comment: if i unregister it gives me this django.contrib.admin.sites.NotRegistered: The model User is not registered

Comment: @NitaAlexandru could be lots of reasons at this point. Just follow the docs. There are examples there.